# How to align text line-by-line in HTML

Tags: html, text

Im trying to get the `p` on `first-class-attributes` and stick it in with the `h3` line-by-line.

I expected it to work when i debugged it, but it spaced up, i went to inspect it but...
the `h3` took the line and i couldn't fix it.

```html
    <div class="image-title">
        <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/roblox/images/2/26/B2rv9XFCIAAWr5r.png/revision/latest?cb=20150217192427" alt="*" draggable="false" width="436">
    <div class="first-class-titles">
        <u><h3>Sign in</h3></u>
    <div class="first-class-attributes">
        <p>(It's free)</p>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: Note: `<h3>` cannot be a child of `<u>`. Fix that error first.

Comment: You can't fix most styling with HTML, only CSS but you don't show any CSS. I also don't know what you mean by "spaced up".

Comment: @Rob by that i mean making a underlined text big enough without taking a line of space.

Comment: Now I understand what you are doing. Put the `<u>` within the `<h3>` and see if that is what you want. Right now, what you have is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To align text line-by-line, you can use CSS to set the display property of the elements to "inline-block" or "table-cell". Here's an example CSS rule to align the "Sign in" and "(It's free)" text:

```
.first-class-titles, .first-class-attributes {
display: inline-block;
}
```

This will align the two elements horizontally, one next to the other. If you want to align them vertically, you can use the CSS "vertical-align" property. For example:

```
.first-class-titles, .first-class-attributes {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```